# The [static] tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[static](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/static) (26) refers to both *things being motionless* and *noise*.

Comment: So... what now?

Comment: I was hoping someone else would tell me :P

Answer (score 5):

Let's retag to what's appropriate:

- [static-ip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/static-ip)
- [static-discharge](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/static-discharge)
- [cdn](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cdn) (serving static files?)
- [noise](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/noise)

If you don't like the situation, consider upvoting [this really amazing MSO proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/151367).

Comment: Already upvoted it.